# How to make a type editable in properties window in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For example we have these type

```
public struct Vector2D
{
    public double X{get; set;}
    public double Y{get; set;}
}
```

One of my user control has property named `Value` with type `Vector2D`

Currently if I look up that property. It will display `<namespace>.Vector2D` and is not editable. (Note that that property is editable and that  is not literally displayed as that)

How to make that property editable via properties window in Visual Studio, just like `Point`, `Size`, `Padding`, etc?

Tries to add `BrowsableAttribute`, `EditorAttribute` with no argument, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but VS is not `Unity` or something else, you have to initialize/assign your properties manually through code (if I understood your question correctly).

Comment: @SeM that type is the type of one of the control's property. If that property has type `int` or `string`, it is editable.

Comment: it could be that your property is not public. add public infront of it. I also recommend overriding the ToString function which a format of your choosing. if that all doesnt work I have a way of custom editing your values in a property grid. but that only works if the struct itself is a property itself of a different class

Comment: @DaanV it is public in actual code, though.

Comment: ill post my custom editor code for propertygrid then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you mean editing the variable through the PropertyGrid control. if so you can call on a custom property editor to edit that specific object. I also recommend overriding the ToString function which a format of your choosing. the PropertyGrid uses that fill in the value to display to the user.

how to implement custom editor:

```
public struct Vector2D : UITypeEditor
{
    //UITypeEditor Implementation

    //Gets the editor style, (dropdown, value or new window)
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    //Gets called when the value has to be edited.
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        //Calls a dialog to edit the object in
        EditTypeConfig editor = new EditTypeConfig((TypeConfig)value);
        editor.Text = context.PropertyDescriptor.Name;

        if (editor.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return editor.SelectedObject;
        else
            return (TypeConfig)value;
    }

    //Properties

    [DisplayName("X"), Description("X is something"), Category("Value"), ReadOnly(false)]
    public double X { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Y"), Description("Y is something"), Category("Value"), ReadOnly(false)]
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Sample
{
    [DisplayName("Value"), Description("Value is something"), Category("Vectors"), ReadOnly(false)]
    [Editor(typeof(Vector2D), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public Vector2D Value { get; set; } 
//Editor(typeof(Vector2D)) calls a class that handles the the editing of that value
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: Struct cannot inherit class.

Comment: where is TypeConfig and EditTypeConfig?

Comment: Ooh sorry, typeconfig was my original class that implemented that UITypeEditor, replace it with your class that implements UiTypeEditor and EditTypeConfig is a Windows form that allows you to custom build something that can edit the relevant objects, an example of this would be the tabcontrol editor, of most collection editor in the property grid control